# Is it possible to return a list of Objects for a mutation in graphene?

Tags: python, graphene-python, graphene-django

I've created a mutation to process data in files. These files are represented by a django model called `MyModel`.

Initially I've taken only one MyModel at a time with his id, but now I've thought that could be better to take a list of MyModel's ids and process them.

So I correct my mutation in this way:

It works fine! But now I want to return the `ifile_list` (it contains MyModel objects that were processed) and show in graphql console their ID. Is it possible? If yes, how? What should I correct or add?
I don't want the solution, but only some concepts that give me the possibility to do that alone.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for bad english!

Comment: Do you have a mutate method in your mutation class?  You would want to update what your mutation class returns.

Comment: Yes.  For example see https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/mutations/ which returns a QuestionMutation object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have something like this:

```py
class ProcessedFile(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = graphene.ID()
    is_processed = graphene.Boolean()

class FileMutation:
    processed_files = graphene.List(
        ProcessedFile,
        incomingfile_list_id=List(ID, required=True)
    )

    def resolve_process_file(self, info, incomingfile_list_id, **kwargs):
        try:
            ifile_list = []
            if not incomingfile_list_id:
                return False
            for id in incomingfile_list_id:
                ifile_list.append(IncomingFileType.objects(info, "write").get(id=id))
            results = []
            for incomingfile in ifile_list:
                is_processed = incomingfile.process()
                # I assume that id can be retrieved
                results.append(ProcessedFile(id=incomingfile.id, is_processed=is_processed))       
          
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error on request to process incoming files from {e}")
            return []
        return results
```

or using existing `IFileType`

```py
class FileMutation:
    processed_files = graphene.List(
        IFileType,
        incomingfile_list_id=List(ID, required=True)
    )

    def resolve_process_file(self, info, incomingfile_list_id, **kwargs):
        try:
            ifile_list = []
            if not incomingfile_list_id:
                return False
            for id in incomingfile_list_id:
                ifile_list.append(IncomingFileType.objects(info, "write").get(id=id))
            for incomingfile in ifile_list:
                incomingfile.process()      
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error on request to process incoming files from {e}")
            return []
        return ifile_list
```